# Trying to build OpenSfm but my OpenCv build doesn't have the proper Cmake file

Tags: opencv

I tried running 'python setup.py build' to build Open SfM. I had used the instructions off the OpenCV website to build OpenCV using gitbash and Cmake in my lib folde without any errors.

However the OpenSfM build error says:   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

```
OpenCVConfig.cmake
opencv-config.cmake
```

I can't for the life of me find these files. I tried downloading the OpenCv package again and running it through a Cmake GUI but I get an error saying there's no CmakeLists.txt files.

Help?

Comment: Can you add links to the instructions you mention? Can you specify your OS? Assuming Windows due to gitbash. You could try searching for that file using `find` in gitbash: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to not just generate the files using CMake but also use either an application like VisualStudio or command line to build the files.
Once you build the files, the OpenCVConfig.cmake files are generated, which you use to point to the OpenSFM compilation.